# Forward Windows 10 "Windows" To X11

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu

Let's assume that I have a Windows 10 VM running under Qemu, there is a way to forward to X11, the windows application.
Something like I start the virtual machine, and I can see only the program without seeing the whole windows desktop.

Comment: This is basically asking "How do I make Windows use the X11 protocol?". IMHO, that's primarily a Windows-related question, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: if your windows program can run under wine, then wine apps can either run in a virtual desktop or as a window on the linux desktop.

Comment: Search for SeamlessRDP which could then be used with the `-A` option of `rdesktop`. For that to work, you'll have to install stuff on the windows side.

Answer (score 2):

I manage to achieve this using `freerdp` with the `/app` option like for example `/app:mspaint`
And on the guest you should add this to the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\TSAppAllowList]
    "fDisabledAllowList"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 1):

It requires the installation of Virtualbox Guest Additions or VMWare Tools on the guest OS but this does exist, just not through the X protocol.  It's also not entirely reliable and you may never get it to work, depending often on how much the client OS uses GPU features.  On Virtualbox this is called "seamless mode" and is a transparent-window-based alternative to fullscreen.  VMware has a similar feature called Unity Mode which I have no experience with.